# Joining with dynamic sql

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic, join

I have the following dynamic sql query which works as intended.  But now I want to join the result with the result of another query on account_id.  I tried the usual way by making the query a derived table then joining but this doesn't work (I assume it has to do with all the semi-colons).  Is there a special way to join a dynamic sql query with another query ?

```
    SET @sql = NULL;
  SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN phone_name = ''',
      phone_name,
      ''' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS `',
      phone_name, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yt;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT account_id, ', @sql, ' 
            from yt
            group by account_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you simply put the rest of your query in your concatenation?

```
...
/* Your existing code */
SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT account_id, ', @sql, ' 
            from yt
            group by account_id');

/* Now put your derived table stuff in */
SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('select a.account_id, b.something_else
            from some_table as b join (', @sql, ') as a
            on a.account_id = b.account_id');

/* Continue your existing code */
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
...
```

Comment: it looks like you are saying I should put this new code in the middle of my current code. But where exactly in my current code should I put it?

Comment: Before you prepare your existing @sql, simply add whatever you wish to it to make your query, then prepare.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by adding another set@sql=concat(...) which included the joining operation.  In it I joined my other query with (',@sql,') on account_id. Thanks!